# Returning callback with jsonp and php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, jsonp

Is it possible return "two ways" with JSONP and php?

Something like this ... E.G

jquery / JSONP

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://server/po.php',
    cache : false,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    timeout: 30000,
    type: 'GET',
    data: {a: 'hello'},
    success:function (json){
        alert(json);
    },
    error:function (e){
        alert('error');
    }
});
```

PHP : po.php

```
if ($conUser == 'hello'){
    echo $_GET['callback']."(". json_encode($a). ")";
}else{
    echo $_GET['callback']."(". json_encode($b). ")";
}
```

Return to me error ... How can i solve this problem?

Comment: What do you see in the browser console? Show us the generated response.

Comment: "_Return to me error_" ... Go on...

Comment: Your PHP can interface with the moon if you want it to, so long as the response is correctly formatted JSON. What is the error you get?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan ... I need to get the message of $a or $b, but it return the error message... the same that i have in: error:function(e){ alert('error');}

Comment: @JasonP ... my answer is for you too :)

Comment: @user2647038 check the console for more details about the error. Also, where are `$a` and `$b` being set?

Comment: Please read the [`jQuery.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) documentation for the **error** function. If you add the missing variables, the reason for the error will be available.

Comment: Hey bro, thanks for your question, i got my answer from your question (not in given answer but only on question).

Answer (score 1):

Just see the [documentation for jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> error
>   `Type: Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown )`

Capture all the variables and then use them.

```
error:function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
    alert(errorThrown);
}
```

Also look at your browser's JavaScript console and other errors may appear there.

Comment: I have this: Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://server/po.php?callba…91003689792612567544_1381506013669&mobile=923323233&uii=b4&_=1381506013670". jquery-1.9.1.js:8336
send jquery-1.9.1.js:8336
jQuery.extend.ajax jquery-1.9.1.js:7978
(anonymous function) javascript.js:446
jQuery.event.dispatch jquery-1.9.1.js:3074
elemData.handle